# ¿Cómo mostrar una imagen de un campo blob?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

Hola quisiera saber como mostrar imágenes almacenadas en campos blob con codificación 64

```
              if (isset($_POST['Enviar'])) {

                if (isset($_FILES['foto']['name'])) {
                  
                include ("configuracion/config.php");

                $tipoArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['type'];
                $nombreArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['name'];
                $tamanoArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['size'];
                $imagenSubida=fopen($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],'r');
                $binariosImagen=fread($imagenSubida,$tamanoArchivo);
                $binariosImagen=mysqli_escape_string($conexion,$binariosImagen);
                $destino='foto/';
                $file = $destino.basename($_FILES['foto']['name']);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $file);
               

                $conexion->query("INSERT INTO foto (Nombre,Foto,Tipo) values('$nombreArchivo','$binariosImagen',' $tipoArchivo')");
              
                echo "<img src='data:image/;base64," . base64_decode($binariosImagen).">";

                header( "refresh:0.5; url=" );

                } 
              }  
           `
```

tambien me gustaría saber como subir múltiples imágenes desde un solo input file

Comment: Intentaste con base64_encode?

Comment: Ademas tené en cuenta que `$binariosImagen` esta esapada con `mysqli_escape_string`. Considera crear otra variable para guardar el valor que vas insertar en la DB

Comment: Como dijo @Bicho, deberías probar así  `echo "<img src='data:image/;base64," . base64_encode($binariosImagen).">";` para mas referencias puedes recurrir al manual de php https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-encode.php